# MBP can't connect to Starbucks Wi-Fi, only restart helps

Tags: macos, network, wifi, safari

Tough question to frame ;) .. but I have a situation that plays out often: firing up the laptop (latest MacBook 15") at Starbucks will often never connect unless I restart the entire box. This tells me there is something amiss somewhere, to which I have no clue. I run nothing out of the ordinary and see no pattern.

I wondered if there was a terminal command that could somehow "reset" network settings. The Wi-Fi is seen properly, and attempts the connection but sits and sits and sits. It eventually connects but it is far faster to restart.

Tough one perhaps, just thought to ask.. thx..

Comment: I've not had this problem on a MB, but I have on Win7 laptop at $tarbuck$.  On Win7 I've discovered I can toggle wifi off and back on and win7 will the connect correctly.  I've never figured out why it doesn't like to on the first try.

Comment: PS- Suggestion for a title revision... drop "secret to", including those words makes it seem like you're seeking a loophole to the normal connection.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to create a new Location. Go to **System Preferences > Network**

Click on Location as the top and pick Edit Locations...

Click the + at the bottom and call it Starbucks or something.

Comment: This, and every possible solution i can muster, makes not difference. The only solution i can find is to reset my laptop... not a huge deal due to the SSD but still a pain. 
And thanks, the title edit was perfect.